# Indirect variable modification not working withing class, but works outside of class (Python 3.7)

Tags: python-3.x

Since I get variable definitions from an external text file i need to modify my local variables indirectly.

What I want to do is basically working, but not once I try to implement it within a class.

```py
X = "0"
vars()["X"]+="1"
print(X) #gives "01" as expected

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        x = "0"
        vars()["x"]+="1"
        self.x = x

test = Test()
print(test.x) # gives "0", but why?
```

While the procedual code snip produces the expected result "01", the code inside the class does not ("0"). Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what the manuals says about `vars` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

> Return the **dict** attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object with a **dict** attribute.
>
> Objects such as modules and instances have an updateable **dict** attribute; however, other objects may have write restrictions on their **dict** attributes (for example, classes use a types.MappingProxyType to prevent direct dictionary updates).
>
> Without an argument, vars() acts like locals(). Note, the locals dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals dictionary are ignored.

In other words, when writing directly you are at the module level that has a writable `__dict__`, not so when you are inside a method.

Although this is bad practice and is not recommended, but this can help you get going:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = '0'
        self.__dict__['x']+='1'

test = Test()
print(test.x) # gives "01"
```

Comment: So the documentation is wrong? It says vars() without argument always gives a read-only dictionary, but at module level it's writeable.

Comment: Not wrong, just incomplete, because the documentation for `locals()` has this note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing a lot of things here. First I will comment on your code:

```
X = "0"
vars()["X"]+="1"
print(X) #gives "01" as expected

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        global X
        x = "0" # this is a local variable inside __init__()
        vars()["X"]+="1" # vars() only shows local variables, will lead to an key error because vars()['X'] does not exist
        self.x = x # assign member variable with value of local variable

test = Test()
print(test.x) # gives "0", because you just assigned self.x = x, which is "0"
```

You could use the `global` keyword to make X visible inside **init**() but this is considered bad practice.

```
X = "0"

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        global X
        self.x = X + "1"

test = Test()
print(test.x) # gives "01"
```

You better initalize `Test` with the variable needed:

```
X = "0"

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, myvar: str):
        self.x = myvar + "1"

test = Test(X)
print(test.x) # gives "01"
```

Comment: His question has vars()['x'], not capital X in the __init__ function now, maybe not when you saw it, but it does make the question more interesting.

Comment: He changed it afterwards, this will now not lead to a key error, but will just get the content of the local variable 'x', which is "0".

Comment: so the question seems to be, why does vars()["x"] += "1" change the variable when used at module level, but not inside a function.

Comment: Because `classes use a types.MappingProxyType to prevent direct dictionary updates`, but why would you write variables inside your class with vars() when you just can use them the normal way?

Comment: I never changed my original post, capital and lower letter were always as they were.

Comment: @Frieder: The reason why I modify my variable inside the class is the following: I am evaluating some (to me) rather complicated polynomial functions. The polynom parameters are stored in an external file. It is possible that terms for a polynom are defined in different lines in that text file, therefore I can not define my varialbe in one step. In the text file the reference to the polynom is obviously given as string. during __init__ i assemble my polynom string, later I pass it to sympy to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

[The documenation for `vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) without an argument says:

> Without an argument, vars() acts like locals(). Note, the locals dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals dictionary are ignored.

But that is incomplete. [The documentation for `locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) says:

> Note that at the module level, locals() and globals() are the same dictionary.

And changes to the dictionary returned by [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) are **not** ignored as it is the actual symbol table:

> Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from which it is called).

So by this really strange design, `vars()` when used at module level actually does return the writeable symbol table -- and anywhere else, it uses a view on which writes are ignored.

None of this really matters, as using these functions is usually a good sign that you're doing something wrong, but still, here it is.

Comment: I know what I ask for is pretty odd, still this way I am able to move forward fast (I just need it for a script to evaluate some formulas, and the polynomial parameters of that function lie in an external text file).